# Time to event analysis in R to explore the effect of a biomarker on an event risk

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

In R, I analyse time-to-event data to explore the effect of a biomarker on an event risk, adjusting for gender. To do this, I work with data that looks like this toy dataset:

```
> head(data)
  pt sex age_baseline t_event death  t_stop biomarker
1  1   M         24345    3632     0   3981      0.22
2  2   F         25951    1121     0   3693      0.14
3  3   F         26900      NA     0   4437      0.04
4  4   F         27521    4896     1   5420      0.35
5  5   F         25660      NA     0   4035      0.25
```

Description of columns:

- **pt**: individual's ID
- **sex**: gender (M=male, F=female)
- **age_baseline**: the age of the individual (in days) at the start of the study
- **t_stop**: time (in days) between baseline and death / last news
- **death**: death (0=no, 1=yes)
- **t_event**: time (in days) between baseline and first occurrence of the event (NA = no event)
- **biomarker**: level of biomarker at baseline

For clarity, an individual may experience event x, and later die of an unrelated cause.

To do so, I'd like to use the `coxph()` R function to compute the Cox model.

I thought of the following code:

```
coxph(
  Surv(time = age_baseline, time2 = t_stop, event = death) ~ t_event + sex, 
       data = data.coro)
```

Does this make sense for my original research question? How can I include `biomarker`?

Also, does the Cox model handle missing data (NAs in `t_event`)?

Comment: You may want to post this in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), which provides more statistical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a Cox PH model, your data set should contain an `event time` and information whether the `event` happened or whether there is censoring:

```
data <- data.frame(pt = seq(1,5), sex = c("M",rep("F",4)), age_baseline = c(24345,25951,26900,27521,25660), 
                       t_event = c(3632,1121,NA,4896,NA), death = c(0,0,0,1,0), t_stop = c(3981,3693,4437,5420,4035), 
                       biomarker = c(0.22,0.14,0.04,0.35,0.25))


# If there is no event, the last follow-up is the censor date
data$t_event[which(is.na(data$t_event))] <- data$t_stop[which(is.na(data$t_event))]
# Adding an event description. If no event, that means the patient gets censored
data$event <- ifelse(is.na(data$t_event),0,1)
```

Now that you have both the `event time` and `event` information (note that above also handles your `NA`), you can build your Cox model with both `sex` and `biomarker` as covariate:

```
coxph(Surv(t_event, event) ~ sex + biomarker, data = data)
```

This gives:

```
> coxph(Surv(t_event, event) ~ sex + biomarker, data = data)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(t_event, event) ~ sex + biomarker, data = data)

              coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z     p
sexM       1.38086   3.97831  1.44998  0.952 0.341
biomarker -3.34641   0.03521  4.48310 -0.746 0.455

Likelihood ratio test=1.32  on 2 df, p=0.5167
n= 5, number of events= 5
```